# Installation problem /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: dpkg

Anything I tried to install I get this error message:

```
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
  Errors were encountered while processing:
   linux-image-3.2.0-23-generic-pae
   linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
   linux-image-3.2.0-26-generic-pae
   linux-image-3.2.0-27-generic-pae
   linux-image-3.2.0-30-generic-pae
  E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried most of the tips people say:
`apt-get upgrade`, `apt-get -f install`, `apt-get update`.
and I've always got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of a fellow from lauchpad, I found the solution for my problem.
It was related with edition problems of grub.cfg
[Here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/225596) is the  complete discussion at lauchpad.
And the direct link to the solution is [here](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=79168&p=461976).
Well, of course the grub.cfg varies from user to user and so  its possible editing errors.

Answer (score 0):

i had this issue due to the fact that Boot partition was full

check via

```
df -h
```

I free up by removed old kernels

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-headers-*


sudo dpkg --remove linux-headers-3.5.0-28*
```

and the image:

```
sudo dpkg --remove linux-image-3.5.0-28*
```

**Make sure you keep you last two kernels** `uname -a` (well at least the last one but for extra safety last two make sure you set the * right)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with dovecot-imapd:

```
 invoke-rc.d: initscript dovecot, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing dovecot-imapd (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dovecot-imapd
```

I tried `apt-get upgrade`, `apt-get -f install`, `apt-get update`, `apt-get clean`, `apt-get autoclean`, and nothing worked.

Suddenly I realized dovecot-core was still installed and after I uninstalled dovecot-core it work.

So Always check for other dependencies :)

Answer (score -2):

Try:

`sudo apt-get clean`

`sudo apt-get autoclean`

then try again.

Hope it works.

Comment: could you please explain what they are and what they will do to help the OP problem.

Comment: If the packages are corrupt, they would cause this error of not being able to install, so if we got rid of the bad packages and re-downloaded them, then it should then work when you re-download them. Basicly, it gets rid of the packages in cache.

Comment: thank @user133987 but unfortunately   it didn't work